# Show that the image in jacobian has an ordinary double point

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, singularity-theory

I'm solving this problem from 11.12 in Birkenhake C., Lange H. - Complex abelian varieties.

[image]

Here $W_2$ is an image of $\mu:C^{(2)}\longrightarrow \operatorname{Pic}^2(C)$. Using Rhiemann singularity theorem I've shown that $\operatorname{dim} \operatorname{Sing}W_2=0$ and that it is actually one point. Also by Riemann's Singularity theorem $\operatorname{mult}(l)=h^0(l)=2$. Hence I know that the singularity is a double point, but I have no clue why this is an ordinary double point. So my question is "How to show that this is an ordinary double point?".

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First solution:** You can calculate the self-intersection of the rational curve $E=\mu^{-1}(p)$. If it is $-2$, then the contraction gives an ordinary node. Here is a way to prove it: Let
$$f:C\times C\to C^{(2)}$$
be the double cover branched at the diagonal. By definition, the pullback $F=f^{-1}(E)$ is the correspondence curve $\{(x,\tau(x))\in C\times C|x\in C\}$ which is isomorphic to $C$, where $\tau$ is the involution given by canonical mapping.

We first compute the self-intersection of $F$. By adjunction formula

$$K_{F}=(K_{C\times C}\otimes [F])|_{F}.$$

Intersection with $F$ on both sides, using the fact that $K_F\cdot F=\deg(K_F)=4$ and $K_{C\times C}=\pi_1^*K_C\otimes \pi_2^*K_C$ where $\pi_i$ is projection to $i$-th coordinate and the intersection of $F$ with a vertical or horizontal curve is $1$, we get $4=8+F\cdot F$, so $F\cdot F=-4$.

How to compute $E\cdot E$? By projection formula
$$f_*F\cdot E=f_*(F\cdot f^*E)$$

together with $f_*F=2E$ and $f^*E=F$ as divisors, we conclude that $E\cdot E=-2$.

**Second Solution:** Alternatively, Riemann singularities theorem also tells you the projective tangent cone of the singularity at the theta divisor, more precisely from Griffiths and Harris, page 343

> The projective tangent cone to $W_d$ at point $\mu(D)$ is the union
> $$T_{\mu(D)}=\bigcup_{\lambda\in \mathbb P^r} \bar{D}_{\lambda},$$
> where $D$ is a degree $d$ effective divisor on $C$ varies in a $r$-dimensional linear system, and $\bar{D}_{\lambda}$ is a $(d-r-1)$-plane in $\mathbb P^{g-1}$ spanned by $p_1(\lambda),...,p_d(\lambda)$.

Now apply to your case where $g=3$ and $C$ is hyperelliptic, and the linear system is a $g_1^2$ (which means $d=2$ and $r=1$), so the projective tangent cone of the isolated singularity at $W_2$ is just the canonical curve of $C$, i.e., a *smooth conic* in $\mathbb P^2$. Smoothness implies that the double point is nondegenerate, so it is an ordinary double point.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you explain why $\deg(K_F)=4$ and $\pi_1^* K_C\cdot F=4$?

Comment: @KirillLosev $F$ is isomorphic to $C$, which has genus $3$, so its canonical bundle has degree $2\times 3-2=4$. Similarly, $\pi_1^*K_C$ consists of $4$ vertical lines in the product, so it's intersection number with the correspondence curve $F$ is $4$.

Comment: thanks! Somehow I got confused and thought that the genus is two.

Comment: Another question. Can we describe $F=f^{-1}(E)$ in general case? For example when $C$ is a smooth non-hyperelliptic curve with $g(C)=2$. All I can say is that F is a double cover of $\mathbb{P}^1$. Is it possible to count $\deg(K_F)$? Thank you.

Comment: @KirillLosev That's right. For $C$ being a hyperelliptic genus $g$ curve, $\deg(K_F)=2g-2$. The same formula shows that $F\cdot F=2-2g$ and $E\cdot E=1-g$. In particular, when $g=2$, the map $C^{(2)}\to W_2$ is a smooth contraction (and $W_2$ is the Jacobian $J(C)$). When $g\ge 3$, $W_2$ has an isolated $A_{g-2}$-singularity.

Comment: Do  you mean non-hyperelliptic?

Comment: And what about genus of F? I think we can use Riemann-Hurwitz formula, but what about ramification points?

Comment: @KirillLosev I mean hyperelliptic curve (so there is a $g_1^2$ and $C^{(2)}\to W_2$ contracts a rational curve. For non-hyperelliptic, this is an isomorphism). $F$ is always isomorphic to $C$ since it is the graph of involution.

Comment: Thanks for your patience

Comment: "$F$  is always isomorphic to $C$ since it is the graph of involution." This is hyperelliptic involution since $F$ is a double cover of $\mathbb{P}^1$, right?

Comment: @KirillLosev Let $C$ be a hyperelliptic curve of genus $g$. By Riemann Singularity theorem, $E$ is the linear system consists of unordered pair $\{p,q\}$, such that $p+q$ lies in the linear system $g_1^2$ which defines $2:1$ map to $\mathbb P^1$ (so $\tau(p)=q$). Then by definition, $F$, as the inverse image of $E$ in $C\times C$ consists of the set of ordered pair $(p,\tau(p))$, $p\in C$, which is the graph of the involution. Everything just follows from Riemann singularity theorem.

Comment: @KirillLosev Replace "Riemann Singularity theorem" by "Abel's theorem" in my previous comment. It is Abel's theorem saying fibers of the Abel-Jacobi map are complete linear systems. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I still have a question about $F$ for non-hyperelliptic curve. Let $g(C)=2$, than $K_C \in \operatorname{Pic}^2(C)$. The fiber in $C^{(2)}$ is $E = \lvert K_C \rvert$ and I want to use same method to show that $E\cdot E = -1$. I am confused about $F = f^{-1}(E)$. My hypothesis is that F is hyperelliptic curve, since $\lvert K_C \rvert \cong \mathbb{P}^1$ and $f$ is a double cover. But I suspect this is not true

Comment: @KirillLosev Every genus two curve is hyperelliptic.