# Blow up $\operatorname{Pic}^3(C)$ along $C$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, blowup

I want to solve this problem
[image]

from  E. Arbarello, M. Cornalba, P. A. Griffiths, J. Harris (auth.) - "Geometry of Algebraic Curves Volume I"

I can show that the fibers of $\{(K_C-P) \in \operatorname{Pic}^3(C) |  P\in C\}$ are $\mathbb{P}^1$  using R-R theorem. For other points $u$ is isomorphism. But I can't understand why this map should be blow up. Probably there are some criteria (e.g. Castelnuovo's Contractibility Theorem but for higher dimension). Than we can do something similar to the first answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3812264/show-that-the-image-in-jacobian-has-an-ordinary-double-point/3813632).

Thanks

Comment: If you think it could be feasible to compute the normal bundle of the exceptional divisor, there is a contractability criterion due to Fujiki-Nakano. I don't know a great reference (the original paper is in the language of complex geometry), but the statement is in Remark 11.10 of Huybrecht's book on Fourier-Mukai Transforms (easily accessible at the cost of a Google search)....

Comment: ...The idea is that if you have a projective bundle $P$ over a smooth variety $Y$, with $P$ sitting as a divisor in some larger variety $\tilde X$, you can contract $P \to Y$ within $\tilde X$ to get a smooth variety $X$ *if* the normal bundle to the projective bundle has degree $-1$ on each fiber. And the criterion also says that $\tilde X$ was the blowup of $X$ along $Y$ in the first place. So to tie this back to Castelnuovo's Criterion, basically you want the fibers to be what one might call relative $(-1)$-curves.

Comment: Every birational map is a blowup (Hartshorne, II, 7.17) along some ideal sheaf. In your case, you need to show the ideal sheaf is reduced.

Comment: @AGlearner Sorry, what did you mean by "ideal sheaf is reduced"?  Do we define ideal sheaf as the kernel of $i^{\#}: \mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Pic}^3(C)} \longrightarrow i_{*}\mathcal{O}_{C}$?